# How to prevent self-intersections when using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, polygon, self-intersection

I've been having an issue while drawing polygons using this PyQGIS code below. Specifically, I've been encountering self-intersection and I don't know how to fix it. Any advice or suggestions?

```
num_points_dialog = QInputDialog()
num_points_dialog.setInputMode(QInputDialog.IntInput)
num_points_dialog.setIntMinimum(3)
num_points_dialog.setIntMaximum(10)
num_points, ok1 = num_points_dialog.getInt(None, "Enter Number of vertices", "Enter the 
number of vertices between 3 and 10:")
vertices = []
if ok1:
    for i in range(num_points):
        while True:
            coord_dialog = QInputDialog()
            coord_dialog.setInputMode(QInputDialog.TextInput)
            coord_str, ok2 = coord_dialog.getText(None, "Enter Coordinates", f"Enter the Latitude and Longitude for vertex {i+1} in DDMMSS format separated by space:")
            if ok2:
                coords = coord_str.split(" ")
                if len(coords) != 2:
                    QMessageBox.warning(None, "Invalid Coordinates", "Please enter two coordinates separated by space.")
                else:
                    lat = dms_to_degrees(coords[0])
                    lon = dms_to_degrees(coords[1])
                    vertices.append(QgsPointXY(lon, lat))
                    break
            else:
                break
shape_geometry = QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([[vertex for vertex in vertices]])
```

Comment: You can't automate self-intersection correction without input into what is wrong, e.g., should a "bowtie" be a quadrilateral or a pair of triangles?  By definition, a ring which forms a polygon boundary can't intersect itself. Yet at some point in digitizing some shapes, there will be a crossing which needs to be resolved before the shape is completed.